# Grails Oracle specific DB properties

Tags: oracle, grails

I want to set the properties connection_property_default_lob_prefetch_size for an oracle DB connection.

Here is how I did it in JAVA. Now I want to do it in grails.

```
        Properties p = new Properties(2);

        String rowPrefetch = "1000";
        String lobPrefetch = "40000000";

        p.setProperty(OracleConnection.CONNECTION_PROPERTY_DEFAULT_ROW_PREFETCH, rowPrefetch);
        p.setProperty(OracleConnection.CONNECTION_PROPERTY_DEFAULT_LOB_PREFETCH_SIZE, lobPrefetch);
        ds.setConnectionProperties(p);
```

I tried to set it in the application.yml but it does not look like it is picking it up.

```
        dataSource:
            dbCreate: none
            url: jdbc:oracle:thin:@1.1.1.1:1521:mydb
            properties:
                jmxEnabled: true
                initialSize: 3
                maxActive: 10
                minIdle: 3
                maxIdle: 7
                maxWait: 10000
                maxAge: 600000
                timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis: 5000
                minEvictableIdleTimeMillis: 60000
                validationQuery: SELECT 1 from dual
                validationQueryTimeout: 15
                validationInterval: 15000
                testOnBorrow: true
                testWhileIdle: true
                testOnReturn: false
                jdbcInterceptors: ConnectionState
                defaultTransactionIsolation: 2 # TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITTED
                dbProperties:
                    connection_property_default_lob_prefetch_size: 40000000
```

I updated the config to look like this, but still nothing.

```
            dbCreate: none
            url: jdbc:oracle:thin:@1.1.1.1:1521:mydb
            properties:
                jmxEnabled: true
                initialSize: 3
                maxActive: 10
                minIdle: 3
                maxIdle: 7
                maxWait: 10000
                maxAge: 600000
                timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis: 5000
                minEvictableIdleTimeMillis: 60000
                validationQuery: SELECT 1 from dual
                validationQueryTimeout: 15
                validationInterval: 15000
                testOnBorrow: true
                testWhileIdle: true
                testOnReturn: false
                jdbcInterceptors: ConnectionState
                defaultTransactionIsolation: 2 # TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITTED
                dbProperties:
                    defaultLobPrefetchSize: 500000000
```

I am testing this my taking the injected dataSource  unwrapping the OracleConnection and creating a OracleCallableStatement from it. The value coming in is 32768.

I am using ojdbc11.jar from oracle.

Comment: I think you are probably using the wrong keys, but I am not sure what the correct ones will be.  For example, the value of `OracleConnection.CONNECTION_PROPERTY_DEFAULT_LOB_PREFETCH_SIZE` is `oracle.jdbc.defaultLobPrefetchSize`.

Comment: so I can add oracle.jdbc.defaultLobPrefetchSize: 5555555 to dbProperties?

Comment: You can.  As I said, I don't know what the correct config property keys should be with that driver, but that looks like a suspect.  If that setting doesn't work, try just `defautlLobPrefetchSize`.  If those don't work, please share the version of the driver you are using and I can setup an env to troubleshoot it.

Comment: I am trying with ojdbc8.jar. I have tried multiple variations within the YML but have had no success. I am willing to try different versions if that would help.